# Malformed output from shell text editor using SSH(putty) from windows to mac

Tags: putty, pico

I am using putty to SSH into a mac, if I try to edit a file with pico, nano or vi I get an output similar to this:

```
[username]$ pico textEdit.txt

←)0←7←[?47h←[1;24r←[m←[4l←[?1h←=←[?1h←=←[?1h←=←[?1h←=←[H←[2J←[22B←[7m^G←[m Get Help  ←[7m^O←[m Write
←[1B←[7m^X←[m Exit←[6C←[7m^J←[m Justify   ←[7m^W←[m Where Is  ←[7m^V←[m Next Page ←[7m^U←[m UnCut Tx
t ←[7m^T←[m To Spell  ←[22;35H←[7m[ New File ]←[m←[H←[7m  GNU nano 1.2.4                 File: textEdit.txt ←[1;52H←[m
```

Are there any settings I can change for either putty or my command prompt to allow a correct display of the output? (I haven't found any)

EDIT: I use plink to open the tunnel, if I open putty the regular way it works just fine

I have seen many solutions of using GUI editors over putty but I'd rather use a shell based editor for quick edits.

Comment: Looks like your `TERM` environment variable is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using PuTTY. You're using `plink`. There's a difference.

On Windows, the default Console works rather differently than terminals in Unixes – that is, it does not understand ANSI escape sequences at all (and various console-based programs use special API functions to position the cursor or to change colors).

So PuTTY.exe isn't just a SSH client but also a full terminal emulator on its own. Similarly, if you use Cygwin's `ssh` command, it uses some kind of terminal emulation layer inside `cygwin1.dll`.

Meanwhile, `plink.exe` has nothing of that kind, it is a SSH client only. This means that if you run it in the Windows Console, you will *always* see the raw escape codes as they were originally sent, without any interpretation.

There are three possible solutions:

- run `plink` inside a terminal emulator such as MinTTY;
- install `ssh` from Cygwin;
- use `PuTTY.exe` – it *does* connect you to a shell; it is a GUI program only to be able to draw advanced terminal features.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I thought plink was just a command line version of putty and they had the same features. 

I guess using the putty terminal is not too much of a bother, at least now I know what the problem was.